# strange anonymous javascript function call

Tags: javascript

I was looking at [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/wr9k8z4x) very cool snippet and i came across this weird line in the js
and deleting that prevent the function from being invoked

```
!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!
function(d, w){
   ...
}(document, window);
```

,i wrapped the function with ( ) as it supposed to be and it works as intended.

```
(function(d, w){
    ...
})(document, window);
```

so my question is what is that weird line and why does it work? my wild guest is that it is some kind IIFE...

Comment: its not `!` operator tricky .. !

Comment: To elaborate on the the duplicate: the `+`, `-`, and `!` are all unary operators doing the same thing as the lone `!` in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @apsillers so those duplicates are unnecessary ?

Comment: @MimiEAM Correct, only one `+`, `-`, or `!` is needed for the function to be parsed as a function expression (rather than a function declaration).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

And you are right, it is an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

You can rewrite

```
!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!
function(d, w){
   ...
}(document, window);
```

to

```
!function() {
    ...
}()
```

and it still works. This is because `!` is a unary operator (just like `+`, `-`, and `~` -- see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).
After an unary operator an expression is expected (and evaluated!). The expression can be a function call.

However

```
!function() {
    ...
}()
```

is just another expression, so you can put another unary operator in front of it:

```
+!function() {
    ...
}()
```

You can continue this pattern as you wish.

**Note:** Invoking an anonymous function this way, ignores the return value of the function. So only use this, if you are not interested in the return value.

**Edit:** Added an excellent reference to http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ which Daff mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is actually the single `!` operator there (the entire first line actually does the same thing). This will work just as well:

```
!function(d, w){
   ...
}(document, window);
```

As always I can recommend Ben Almans great article on [Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: thank you, i wish i could accept both answer